# "Stay here more" vs "stay more here"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> You'd  better not stay  here more.

vs.

> You'd  better  not  stay  more  here.

Between these  two  sentences,  which  one  is  correct?  Or  are  they  both correct?

Answer (score 6):

In both sentences the word "more" doesn't fit well. It's preferable to use "anymore" or "any longer" instead.

The verb phrase you are using is "stay here", so the structure should be:

> You'd better not stay here anymore.

or

> You'd better not stay here any longer.

If you want to emphasize the "any longer" part over the "here", you can use the verb "linger" (which means ["remain or stay on in a place longer than is usual or expected"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/linger)) instead:

> You'd better not linger here.